# RECFM =FBA when i specifed RECFM=FB

Tags: jcl

I used IDCAMS to PRINT records in a VSAM KSDS to PS file(created in the JCL).

```
//OUTDD DD DSN=&SYSUID...PUTOUT,DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),
//      SPACE=(TRK,(1,0)),
//      DCB=(RECFM=FB,DSORG=PS,LRECL=120),BLKSIZE=9600
```

Although I specifed RECFM=FB in Jcl, it shows FBA when I look at attributes of Z00838.PUTOUT. I need help?

Comment: Note that the A (or M) indicates that the first character is for carriage control. In almost all cases, print meant for human interpretation on paper is easier with it. ISPF and SDSF note the CC and by default do not display it. The IBM FTP server also changes the CC to control characters such as \f and \n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.idai200/output.htm#output) IDCAMS has some requirements for the output-dataset of the `PRINT` statement that it enforces in a not too obvious way.

The default `SYSPRINT` is `RECFM=VBA,LRECL=125`, but as per above link

> You can alter the defaults by placing other values in the DCB
> parameter of the SYSPRINT statement. You cannot, however, use a record
> format of F or fixed block (FB); those are changed to VBA.

Note the part after the semicolon: IDCAMS will automatically change all DCB-Parameters it does not like.

After playing around with the parameters it seems to be even more strict than stated above: Even `RECFM=VB` will be changed to `VBA` and all `LRECL`s less than 125 will be changed to 125.

P.S.: Do you really want to `PRINT` the dataset like this?

```
RECORD SEQUENCE NUMBER - 69   
//IKJEFT1A EXEC PGM=IKJEFT1A  
RECORD SEQUENCE NUMBER - 70   
//*
```

or do you want to `REPRO` it like this?

> //IKJEFT1A EXEC PGM=IKJEFT1A
> //*

P.P.S.: This behaviour will also affect preexisting datasets that have been allocated with `DISP=SHR`.
The most interesting effect was when using a preexisting FB80-dataset that already has some contents and allocating it with `DISP=MOD` in the IDCAMS `PRINT` step. The step completed with returncode 0 but trying to read the dataset afterwards resulted in an I/O-error.